# What could be the reasons for a slack expired_trigger_id error?

Tags: slack, bolt

At times when I try to open a slack modal, it gives an expired_trigger_id error in production. How do I debug and find out why it is happening? I am using slack bolt in js for creating the chatbot.

Answer (score 2):

The trigger_id expires after 3 seconds. So, if you have any processes in between the command in slack to the point where you attempt to open a modal, 3 seconds could have elapsed. I would start with logging time stamps. My guess is that you have other resources causing a delay that intermittently exceed 3 seconds. Without seeing your code, it's hard to give you a jump point on starting to debug, but I would start with logging.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).